# JS based influxdb graph editors like Grafana, Influga, are there reusable libraries?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, metrics, influxdb, grafana

I have been working with tools like [grafana](http://grafana.org/) or [influga](https://github.com/hakobera/influga), which are fantastic projects which facilitate the creation of dashboards with charts and various type of graphs.

I was wondering, would it be possible to separate the 2 core features of these apps in a standalone javascript library that can be reused in existing web apps (that can be made easy to use by end-users also)?

The 2 key features would be:

- graph editor (query, labels, colors, ecc.)
- graph view (see the graph, change date range, zoom in and out, ecc)

The problem with grafana and similar solutions is that they are not easy to integrate with existing web apps, and these projects are growing in complexity and adding new features, while something many people might need is some kind of integration in existing web apps.

Is there anybody working on this? If yes, what are the 2 most promising projects?

Comment: I am in search of exactly what you are describing. I was able to [retrieve data from influxDB with js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32971011/retrieve-data-from-influxdb-with-client-side-code/33011011#33011011) and create a simple graph with C3.js but the 2 key features you are talking about have to be implemented...

Comment: I'm tired of huge apps that try to do everything, they're good for users but useless for developers. The Unix philosophy has been forgotten.

Answer (score 3):

Grafana v2.0 allows you to use [Embed Panel](http://docs.grafana.org/reference/sharing/) with "iframe" tag.

It's very usefull when you trying to integrate graph in another system.