# Retrieve data from InfluxDB with javascript (client-side, using a browser)

Tags: jquery, ajax, influxdb

I want to build a static html page which retrieves data from influxDB. Is there any jquery/ajax solution or even a js library to do this? I've tried to use [influent](https://github.com/gobwas/influent), an InfluxDB driver for Javascript apps which says it can work in browser but I had no success when I tried to use influent.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I captured with the developer tools the http requests that [Grafana](http://grafana.org/) sends in order to create graphs and tried to do the same with jQuery get():

```
// something like this
$.get("http://localhost:8086/query?db=mydb&epoch=ms&q=SELECT+mean(value)+FROM+%22cpu_load_short%22+WHERE+time+%3E+1443610329s+and+time+%3C+1443629449s+GROUP+BY+time(30s)").done(
   function (data) { console.log(data);
});
```

InfluxDB returns JSON which I later handle and create a graph. See [influxDB - Querying data](https://influxdb.com/docs/v0.9/guides/querying_data.html)

Comment: How would it work for the authentication part? Would I have to include the user and the password in each query making them therefore visible since my javascript app makes http requests?

Answer (score 1):

Influent is the best maintained javascript library for InfluxDB. If it's not working, you would probably be better served to open an issue on the repo than to find another library. I am unaware of any other libraries that are compatible with InfluxDB 0.9